# Teradata (TERAPROD) has an expression called TITLE, but I also have a column named title, cant execute query

Tags: sql, byte, teradata, varchar

I'm using a Teradata environment (TERAPROD) to do a project for someone, one of my column names is TITLE and it should be a varchar, however, it is a varbyte. I have no access to the source code so I cannot change the original query to alter the datatype to varchar ahead of time.

So how do I transform this column from varbyte to varchar. I first tried to eliminate the problem of having the "teradata expression keyword TITLE" by writing `Select "TITLE" from _database_`, but this then produced the varbyte format in the execution. How should I go about this?

Example of what is happening using random query:
lets pretend the value at index 1 is "dictionary" and I run this

`Select title from teradata.view` --Wont Work cause title is expression

'Select "TITLE" from teradata.view' --prints out varbytes of word

What can I do to make this print out varchars without changing source code? or is that only option?

Comment: There's no built-in CAST or function to convert VARBYTE to VARCHAR. One could write a fairly simple UDF for that, or you could potentially retrieve (export) data as just a string of bytes and treat the data as a character string on the client side.

Comment: If this column is actually a varbyte the client should do the conversion. What is returned when you do a `select *`? As long as those bytes are plain ASCII `from_bytes` might work:`select from_bytes('64696374696F6E617279'xb, 'ascii')`